# Desktop Computer - One Second Shutdown

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, power-supply

Hello superuser community.
My computer just died on me yesterday, I've spent over five hours trying to figure out what broke but had no success.

> ### My computer's hardware
>
> **CPU** - Intel I5 2500K @ 3,3 ghz (Never overclocked it)
>
> **MOBO** - Asus P8Z68v-Gen3
>
> **PSU** - Corsair GS700
>
> **RAM** - 8GB 1600mhz CL9 Ripjaws
>
> **HDD** - 1TB WesternDigital 5400rpm
>
> **GPU** - GTX 560Ti DirectCU II TOP
>
> **CPU COOLER** - Corsair A70
>
> **Case** - CM690 Lite

My computer was working fine, I turned it off and went to sleep.
Next morning I woke up and turned on my computer, **it turned on, turned back off, then turned on again and stood there powered on idling and no image was being shown on the monitor, no BIOS or POST messages, not even beeps.** I immediately figured that something was wrong, so I opened up the case, and removed the GPU from the slot, and tried booting it from the motherboard's on-board GPU but still no luck.

After doing this, I tried the next obvious thing, **I tried to reset the BIOS and CMOS, after browsing the web I found out that I should remove the CPU from the socket and then perform a CMOS reset using the jumper**, and so, I did.

**After re-assembling everything I tried to boot my computer, but It does not boot any more.** I press the power button, it turns on for about one second and instantly powers off. The only LED that seems to blink on the motherboard is the CPU_CHECK one.

I've also tried moving the RAMS for their current slots, I've tried various set-ups but to no avail. (The original RAM positions were 0-1-0-1, I've tried 1-0-1-0 and even 1-0-0-0 and 0-0-0-1).

Has my motherboard died on me? Or is the PSU broken? Or do I have faulty RAM? What should I do beyond this point?
Keep in mind that it still does not boot into anything, so I do not have access to BIOS.

(On another note, my computer tends to "electric shock me", but just a tingling feeling, whenever I touch any conductive materials inside the case, but not when I touch the case itself.Maybe this is cause of the problem?)

Answer (score 0):

Small shock on PC cabinet is normal. I don't think that that is the problem for your PC failure. It may be due to faulty CPU,Faulty mother board,or even faulty RAM. I had faced similar issue before. I first thought it to be mother board issue and bought a new one. But it did not work. Upon detailed inspection it turned out that my CPU, RAM and Motherboard all three of them where broken,due to some power surge or something. So it is better to take the PC to a service professional.

Comment: Shoot. Thank you for your answer but that was what I was most afraid to hear, my computer isn't even two years old yet the thought of it breaking down and losing the investment I made is quite sad. I will follow your advise and take it a specialist if nobody else thinks they might have a solution.